# MySql Convert DateTime to Time

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access form displaying data from an MySql DB. I had a column in the db which was a DateTime format. I only needed it to record time. So I changed the format of it to Time format.

When I look at the column in PhpMyAdmin all I see is the time xx:xx:xx.

However when I click into the field in access I displays todays date with the stored time. Similar to a timestamp format. Any idea why this might be happening. I've tried re-linking the tables but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Likely it's the format associated with the form field. Access should have some predefined formats for "time", or you may be able to create a custom format. That's just a guess. Someone that knows more about Access and how your form is defined will likely be able to give you an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the db value to a char string instead of letting access interpret it as a datetime field.

select cast(db.StartTime as char) as StartTime, 
cast(db.EndTime as char) as EndTime

Comment: So when I view the form that is displaying the time I get the full "24/02/2015 22:00:00" when I click out of it, it returns to 22:00. If I do the same with a new DateTime column it just stays at time "22:00" only. Is it possible access doesn't play well with time only fields and needs to add in todays date to compensate?